# AOP redirect invocation

Tags: java, spring, scala, aop, spring-aop

I would like to hack an invocation of an interface method using AOP, and invoke with SPI another implementation by reflection.

There's any way to have an Pointcut/Around where we somehow redirect the invocation?

Here my code base

```
@Around(value = "@annotation(spiExtension)")
def aroundSourceMethod(joinPoint: ProceedingJoinPoint, spiExtension: SpiExtension): Unit = {
    val interfaces = joinPoint.getTarget.getClass.getInterfaces
    for(interface <- interfaces){
      if (implementationLoadedByClazz.get(interface) == null) {
        for (clazz <- ServiceLoader.load(interface)) {
          val extensionClass: SpiExtensions = ComponentUtil.getComponentByImplementation(clazz.getClass, interface)
          implementationsByCondition.put(extensionClass.condition, extensionClass)
          implementationLoadedByClazz.put(interface, extensionClass)
        }
      }
    }
    invokeSpecificImplementation(joinPoint)
  }

  private def invokeSpecificImplementation(joinPoint: ProceedingJoinPoint) = {
    val methodSignature = joinPoint.getSignature.asInstanceOf[MethodSignature]
    val method = methodSignature.getMethod
    val args = joinPoint.getArgs
    val condition = args.apply(0).asInstanceOf[String]
    val instance:Object = implementationsByCondition(condition)
    Proxy.getInvocationHandler(instance).invoke(instance, method, args)
  }
```

As you can see I use reflection invoke the method I want, but what happen with the original request to the method.
We would normally would add `joinPoint.proceed();` in the @Around method

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't work. What's your error?

Comment: what do you mean: "redirect the invocation"?

Comment: infinite loop, I mean If I invoke implementation A and now I want to redirect to implementation B

Answer (score 1):

Infinite loop is because AOP will process your  call the same way as original. You need a way (a flag) to catch such usecase and skip your manipulations for the second call. And also check if you have dynamic proxy, then you can get original function and call it directly.